# Java generics ambiguous method

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior behind the below code. Any help in understanding would be appreciated.

```
class Binder {

    <T> void bind(Class<T> clazz, Type<T> type) {
        System.out.println("clazz type");
    }

    <T> void bind(T obj, Type<T> type) {
        System.out.println("obj type");
    }
}

class Type<T> {
    Type(T obj) { }
}

Binder binder = new Binder();

binder.bind(String.class, new Type<String>("x")) //works

binder.bind(Object.class, new Type<Object>(new Object()))  //ambiguous
```

The above code will fail with

```
ERROR: reference to bind is ambiguous
  both method <T>bind(java.lang.Class<T>,Type<T>) in Binder and method <T>bind(T,Type<T>) in Binder match
```

If I were to remove the second argument to each method, both bind calls would execute the first method

```
class Binder {

    <T> void bind(Class<T> clazz) {
        System.out.println("clazz");
    }

    <T> void bind(T obj) {
        System.out.println("obj");
    }
}

Binder binder = new Binder();

binder.bind(String.class)

binder.bind(Object.class)
```

The above will print "clazz" twice.

Comment: the first method takes instances of the class `Class` while the second method takes generic types to which `Class` does not belong to as also primitive types don't

Comment: @AKSW Class is an instance of Object, so it can be used in generic types

Comment: @Ferrybig hm, ok. I'm just reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3 right now and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6

Comment: @James which of the two behaviours do you found surprising?

Comment: I don't know why, but changing the type of the second `bind` method from `T` to `Object` makes it compile, no ambiguity.  Somehow `T` being there, even if it's inferred to be `Object`, makes it ambiguous?  I don't know why.

Comment: @AndyTurner I find the ambiguous error to be surprising because I would expect `Object.class` to match `Class<T>` over `T`.

Comment: @rgettman so, `<T> void bind(Object obj, Type<T> type) {`? it's because then anything you can use to invoke the first overload can also be used to invoke the second, because any `Class<T>` is an `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this behaviour is adequately explained in [JLS 15.12.2.5 Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> The informal intuition is that one [applicable] method is more specific than another [applicable method] if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

To state this another way, one method is more specific than the other if either of these statements are true:

- Any arguments you pass in a valid invocation of the first method can also be passed in a valid invocation of the second method.
- Any arguments you pass in a valid invocation of the second method can also be passed in a valid invocation of the first method.

Unless the first and second methods are the same, at most one of these statements can be true.

---

An important point about choosing the most specific method is that this is only necessary when more than one method is applicable for the given arguments.

`binder.bind(String.class, new Type<String>("x"))` is not ambiguous because the `<T> void bind(T, Type<T>)` method is not applicable: if you pass a `Type<String>` to that method, the only type which can be inferred for `T` is `String` (because a `Type<T>` is not, say, a `Type<Object>`).

As such, you would have to pass a `String` to that method. `String.class` is a `Class<String>`, not a `String`, so that method is not applicable, so there is no ambiguity to resolve as only one possible method - the `<T> void bind(Class<T>, Type<T>)` - applies.

---

In the ambiguous case, we are passing a `Type<Object>` as the second parameter. This means that, if both overloads are applicable, the first parameter would need to be a `Class<Object>` and an `Object` respectively. `Object.class` is indeed both of those things, hence both overloads are applicable.

To prove that these are ambiguous overloads, we can find a counter example to refute the claim that "any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other" for both methods with respect to the other.

The key word here is *any*: this has nothing to do with the specific arguments that are being passed in here, but is only to do with the types in the method signature.

- The successful invocation (`binder.bind(String.class, new Type<String>("x"))`) couldn't invoke the `bind(T, Type<T>)` overload, because `String.class` isn't a `String`.
- `binder.bind("", new Type<String>(""))` couldn't invoke the `bind(Class<T>, Type<T>)` overload, because `""` is a `String`, not a `Class<String>`.

QED.

This can also be demonstrated by giving one of the methods a different name, say, `bind2`, and attempting to pass these parameters.

```
<T> void bind(Class<T> clazz, Type<T> type) { ... }
<T> void bind2(T obj, Type<T> type) { ... }

binder.bind(String.class, new Type<String>("x")); // compiles
binder.bind2(String.class, new Type<String>("x")); // doesn't compile

binder.bind("", new Type<String>("x")) // doesn't compile
binder.bind2("", new Type<String>("x")) // compiles
```

Giving different names removes the possibility of ambiguity, so you can directly see if the parameters are applicable.

---

In the 1-argument case, anything you can pass to `<T> void bind(Class<T>)` can also be passed to `<T> void bind(T)`. This is because `Class<T>` is a subclass of `Object`, and the bound `T` degenerates to `Object` in the second case, so it accepts anything.

As such, `<T> void bind(Class<T>)` is more specific than `<T> void bind(T)`.

Redoing the renaming demonstration above:

```
<T> void bind3(Class<T> clazz) { ... }
<T> void bind4(T obj) { ... }

binder.bind3(String.class); // compiles
binder.bind4(String.class); // compiles

binder.bind3("") // doesn't compile
binder.bind4("") // compiles
```

Obviously, the fact that `String.class` can be passed to both `bind3` and `bind4` doesn't *prove* there isn't a parameter that can be accepted by `bind3` but not `bind4`. I started by stating an informal intuition, so I'll finish with the informal intuition that "*really*, there isn't one".

Comment: "it is neither the case that anything you pass to <T> void bind(Class<T>, Type<T>) can be passed to <T> void bind(T, Type<T>), nor vice versa" Can you rephrase that? I'm having trouble understanding what that means

Comment: @JamesKleeh any better?

Comment: You say the following is false: "Any arguments you pass in a valid invocation of <T> void bind(Class<T>, Type<T>) can also be passed in a valid invocation of <T> void bind(T, Type<T>)". I don't think that is true. An instance of a `Class` is an object and thus can be passed to `T`

Comment: `bind("", new Type<String>(""))` is not a valid invocation of `bind(Class<T>, Type<T>)`.

Comment: I don't see how that is different from what I said. I don't see how adding the same exact argument to both cases would change anything in regards to which method is more specific.

Comment: That isn't what that statement is saying. Its talking about the other way around.

Comment: Which statement are you referring to, and what is the "that" that it isn't what that statement is saying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199094/discussion-between-james-kleeh-and-andy-turner).

Answer (score 2):

Let me revise System outs like those for my understanding:

```
public class Binder
{
    class Type<T>
    {
        Type( T obj )
        {
            System.out.println( "Type class: " + obj.getClass( ) );
        }
    }
}
```

We can test each of the cases one by one:

### How Object call is ambiguous?

#### 1) Test Object call on Class:

```
<T> void bind( Class<T> clazz, Type<T> type )
{               
   System.out.println( "test clazz bind" );
   System.out.println( "Clazz class: " + clazz );
}

@Test
public void bind_Object( )
{
    Binder binder = new Binder( );
    binder.bind(Object.class, new Type<Object>(new Object());
}
```

#### Output:

```
Type class: class java.lang.Object
test clazz bind
Clazz class: class java.lang.Object
```

#### My explanation:

In this case, T is chosen as Object. So function declaration became as 
`bind(Class<Object> obj, Type<Object>)` which is fine because we are calling with 
`bind(Object.class, new Type<Object)` where `Object.class is assignable to Class<Object>` so this call is fine.

#### 2) Test Object call on T:

```
<T> void bind( T obj, Type<T> type )
{
    System.out.println( "test obj bind" );
    System.out.println( "Obj class: " + obj.getClass() );
}

@Test
public void bind_Object( )
{
    Binder binder = new Binder( );

    binder.bind(Object.class, new Type<Object>(new Object());
}
```

#### Output:

```
Type class: class java.lang.Object
test obj bind
Obj class: class java.lang.Class
```

#### My explanation:

In this case T is chosen as Object. So function declaration became as `bind(Object obj, Type<Object>)` which is fine because we are calling with `bind(Object.class, new Type<Object), Class<Object>` is assignable to `Object` as first param.

So both methods are appropriate for the Object call. But why String call is not ambiguous? Let's test it:

### How String call is NOT ambiguous?

#### 3) Test String call on Class:

```
<T> void bind( Class<T> clazz,Type<T> type )
{
    System.out.println( "test clazz bind" );
    System.out.println( "Clazz class: " + clazz );
}

@Test
public void bind_String( )
{
    Binder binder = new Binder( );

    binder.bind( String.class, new Type<String>( "x") );
}
```

#### Output:

```
 Type class: class java.lang.String

 test clazz bind 

 Clazz class: class java.lang.String
```

#### My explanation:

In this case T is chosen as String. So function declaration became as `bind(Class<String> clazz, Type<String> type)` which is fine because we are calling with `bind(String.class, new Type<String)` which is assignable for sure. How about T bind?

#### 4) Test String call on T:

```
<T> void bind( T obj, Type<T> type )
{
    System.out.println( "test obj bind" );
    System.out.println( "Obj class: " + obj.getClass() );
}

@Test
public void bind_String( )
{
    Binder binder = new Binder( );

    binder.bind( String.class, new Type<String>( "x") );
}
```

#### Output:

*Compiler error*

#### My explanation:

In this case T is chosen as String. So function declaration became as `bind(String obj, Type<String> type)` which is NOT fine because we are calling with `bind(String.class, new Type<String)`. `String.class which means Class<String>`. So we try to call `(String, Type<String>)` function with `(Class, Type<String)` inputs which is not assignable.

Comment: I think that sums up why its ambiguous, however what I still don't understand is why the `Class<T>` is not chosen over `T` for `Object.class`. The class argument is "closer", so it should choose that instead.

Comment: The fact that more than one method is applicable for given arguments is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for ambiguity. In the one-argument case, there are still two methods applicable for the argument, but it is not ambiguous because one is considered more specific than the other.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't understand why adding the same argument to both methods would change that.